# Allocating matrix in fortran - invalid memory reference

Tags: fortran

I'm pretty new to fortran, but I am having trouble assigning values to a matrix over a daily loop. The values that are being inserted into the matrix are from a previous array where I randomly assigned sizes to 125 small and large spot. In this case, the daily loop represent daily fish mortality so the matrix size is dynamic. I am attempting to run the following code with the compiler:

```
gfortran -g Rice_model.f
```

```
         PROGRAM Rice_model
         IMPLICIT NONE
         real, allocatable, dimension (:,:) :: final_spot
         real, dimension(125) :: size_small_spot, size_large_spot
         integer :: days, i, j, n_spot
         real(kind = 8) :: mu_small_spot,lower_small_spot,upper_small_spot, size_of_spot
         real(kind = 8) :: mu_large_spot,lower_large_spot,upper_large_spot

         integer :: seed
         real(kind = 8) :: sigma_spot
         real(kind = 8) :: min, max

         ! defining variables for the truncated normal distribution for sizes
         mu_small_spot = 42.8
         lower_small_spot = 33.0
         upper_small_spot = 49.0

         mu_large_spot = 63.7
         lower_large_spot = 54.0
         upper_large_spot = 78.0
         sigma_spot = 4.0
         seed = 123456789
    
         n_spot = 125
         days = 20

         ! SMALL SPOT
          do i = 1,n_spot
           call truncated_normal(mu_small_spot,sigma_spot,
     &         lower_small_spot,upper_small_spot,seed,size_of_spot)
           WRITE (*,*) i, size_of_spot
           size_small_spot(i) = size_of_spot
          end do
           min = minval (size_small_spot, dim = 1)
           max = maxval (size_small_spot, dim = 1)
           WRITE(*,*) "Min Size = ", min
           WRITE(*,*) "Max Size = ", max

         ! LARGE SPOT
         do i = 1,n_spot
          call truncated_normal(mu_large_spot,sigma_spot,
     &           lower_large_spot,upper_large_spot,seed,size_of_spot)
          WRITE (*,*) i, size_of_spot
          size_large_spot(i) = size_of_spot
         end do
          min = minval (size_large_spot, dim = 1)
          max = maxval (size_large_spot, dim = 1)
          WRITE(*,*) "Min Size = ", min
          WRITE(*,*) "Max Size = ", max

         allocate(final_spot(1:3,n_spot))
         do i = 1,days
           n_spot = n_spot - (n_spot * 0.018)
           do j = 1, n_spot
              final_spot(1,j) = j
              final_spot(2,j) = size_small_spot(j)
              final_spot(3,j) = size_large_spot(j)
           end do
         end do
         deallocate(final_spot)

         WRITE(*,*) "The min values are", minval(final_spot, dim = 1)
         WRITE(*,*) "The max values are", maxval(final_spot, dim = 1)

         END PROGRAM Rice_model
```

It appears to work but anytime I include code to print it won't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't give any value to `n_spot` before using it. (And as it's an integer, it's not clear that `n_spot = n_spot - (n_spot * 0.018)` is a sensible thing.)

Comment: My apologies, forgot to include that part of my code. Will edit accordingly

Comment: If I fix the obvious problem of giving values to the size_*_spot arrays and adding an `end program` statement it works for me, either with or without writing out the final_spot array. Could you shows us please a short **complete** program that displays the error you are encountering, along with how you compiled it

Comment: I have included most of the code for the full model. I did not include the subroutines for sake of space. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: You `deallocate(final_spot)` and then try to find the `minval` and `maxval` of it - this is not going to end well.

Comment: Should I find the min and max values prior to deallocating? My understanding of the deallocation command was that it no longer makes it editable but you could still view it.

Comment: No. When you deallocate it the data is gone. End of story.

Comment: Ok, I will keep that in mind. Thank you so much for your help.